# how to split arrays if the total is close to the specified value of php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have array data with structure like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 20
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 15
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 40
        )
)
```

how to make part from this array provided that each part has an weight total close to 50

i have tried with array_split but it seems that is not the right way

this is my code

```
<?php

$array = array();

$array[] = array
        (
            "weight" => "20"
        );
$array[] = array
        (
            "weight" => "15"
        );

$array[] = array(
            "weight" =>"40"
        );


echo "<pre>";


$arr= array_chunk($array,2);
print_r($arr);

?>
```

i want make result like this

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: can you provide your expected output - currently your question is unclear

Comment: your question is not clear and expected output?

Comment: sorry my english is bad,,, i've edit my ask

Comment: Do you want to put them into groups so that the sum of the weights in the group is lower than 50, i.e. adding another item would bring the sum to a value above 50?

Comment: yes ... if the total weight is above 50 then create a new part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the array with array_column so that it can be easily sorted.
Then loop the array and as long as the values are less than 50 keep adding then to the new array, if above than 50 create a new array item in the new array.

```
$arr = array_column($array, "weight");
sort($arr); 

$i= 0;
$new[0]= [];
foreach($arr as $val){
    if(array_sum($new[$i]) + $val <50){
        $new[$i][] = $val;
    }else{
        $i++;
        $new[$i][] = (int) $val;
    }
}

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/eAitC

Larger sample: https://3v4l.org/FUFQA

Comment: thanks.., but how to display array item

Comment: Echo as usual. You didn't include that in your question. `echo implode("<br>", $new);`

Comment: i have show example result i want..., sorry i edit my ask before

Comment: this the exmaple result 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnccK.png

Comment: See edited code. Now I just add the values to a multidimensional array instead of summing it in the loop.

Comment: thanks.. my bro .. solved

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your question